# Update Method RowInserted Not Called On Submit for Blazorise DataGrid

Tags: datagrid, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I need to have all the CRUD methods be external.  But there is something missing. What?

I set the `UseInternalEditing=false`, define `RowInserting` and the external method `OnRowInserted` is not reached.

###### Code

```
<DataGrid TItem="AppInstructor"
      EditMode="Blazorise.DataGrid.DataGridEditMode.Inline"
      Editable="true"
      RowInserted="@OnRowInserted"
      UseInternalEditing="false"
      ShowValidationFeedback="true"
      Data="@_instService.GetALL()">
<DataGridCommandColumn TItem="AppInstructor">
    <SaveCommandTemplate>
        <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@context.Clicked">Save</Button>
    </SaveCommandTemplate>
    <EditCommandTemplate>
        <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@context.Clicked">Edit</Button>
    </EditCommandTemplate>
</DataGridCommandColumn>
<DataGridColumn TItem="AppInstructor" Field="@nameof(AppInstructor.LastName)" Editable="true" Caption="First Name" Sortable="true">
</DataGridColumn>
<DataGridColumn TItem="AppInstructor" Field="@nameof(AppInstructor.LastName)" Editable="true" Caption="Last Name" Sortable="true">
</DataGridColumn>
```

##### Code section

```
@code {

private void OnRowInserted(SavedRowItem<AppInstructor,
                           Dictionary<string, object>> e)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: One issue is that you are missing `Type="ButtonType.Submit"` for the save button to act as a form submit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `PreventDefaultOnSubmit` to have your custom click event trigger.

```
<SaveCommandTemplate>
    <Button Type="ButtonType.Submit" 
            PreventDefaultOnSubmit 
            Color="Color.Primary"
            Clicked="@context.Clicked">Save</Button>

</SaveCommandTemplate>
```

Then `RowInserted="OnRowInserted"` will be called.